# How can I use single batch file to run some application with my own input redirected to it?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There is an example (let us say in a file named `mybatch.bat`):

```
@echo off
myprogram.exe
input_to_myprogram
another_input_to_myprogram
echo myprogram exit point here, so this is just an echo string
```

When I running `myprogram.exe` (it's a simple console application) it asks me to input some string. When I pass a string to it (`input_to_myprogram`) it asks me for one more input string (`another_input_to_myprogram`). After that `myprogram.exe` is terminating, so all other commands in `mybatch.bat` are simple shell commands (not an input to `myprogram.exe`, because it has been terminated already).
I can use one more file to do the same by replacing call to `myprogram.exe` by `myprogram.exe < myprogram_input.txt` with `myprogram_input.txt` containing

```
input_to_myprogram
another_input_to_myprogram
```

but I can use only one file to do this (`mybatch.bat`).
So it is possible or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `echo` to direct the required strings to myprogram.exe:

```
@echo off
(echo input_to_myprogram & echo another_input_to_myprogram) | myprogram.exe
another_program.exe
```